# I cannot find waterleaf on iPad

Tags: terraria-mobile

So I have been creating many worlds but I can't seem to find any seeds? Could anyone help me in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Seeds only drop from an herb if the plant is blooming when you cut it.

For mobile and console versions of Terraria, waterleaf will only bloom if it is underwater, either partially or fully.  Since waterleaf usually grows on sand in the middle of the desert, it's pretty rare to find one already in a pool of water when you get out there.

Best recommendation is to grab a bucket, fill it with water.  When you find a waterleaf plant, mine up some of the nearby sand, and put it back down surrounding the plant so water won't drain away.  Dump the water in, and presto, plant blooms.  If the water doesn't spread out too far, you can even pick it back up in the bucket and repeat the process at the next waterleaf you find.

[More information can be found here.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Waterleaf)

Comment: Note that in the desktop version of the game, it's only required to be raining for waterleaf to bloom.